# Attempt to load new items for table view by scroll to bottom

Tags: swift

I try to add new items to table view when user hit bottom.

Here is what i tried:

```
 /* Scrolling */

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let height = scrollView.frame.size.height
        let contentYoffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        let distanceFromBottom = scrollView.contentSize.height - contentYoffset
        if distanceFromBottom < height {
            self.viewModel.loadMoreCharacters()
        }
    }
```

`LoadMoreCharacters` func start like this:

```
func loadMoreCharacters(){

        guard isLoading.value == false else {
            print("Already try to load items")
            return
        }
        isLoading.value = true
        print ("start load")

 isLoading.value = true

        ApiManager.shared.getCharacters(offset: offset, limit: limit, orderBy: OrderBy.name) { [unowned self] (success, charIds) in

            if (success){
                self.addItemsWithNewCharactersIds(charIds: charIds ?? [])
                self.offset += 10
                 self.isLoading.value = false
                print("have new")
            }   else {
                self.isLoading.value = false
                self.delegate?.finishLoadingWithError(error: nil)
            }
        }
```

For some reason, that code execute 2 times. I want it to execute single time (i mean request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally wouldn't rely on just the `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate because theres other things that can scroll it as well that may not be from user interaction. You can maybe try utilizing these two delegates to see if it was the user who scrolled

```
var userScrolling = false

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (userScrolling) {
        let height = scrollView.frame.size.height
        let contentYoffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        let distanceFromBottom = scrollView.contentSize.height - contentYoffset
        if distanceFromBottom < height {
            self.viewModel.loadMoreCharacters()
        }
    }
}

func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    userScrolling = true
}

func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    userScrolling = false
}
```

> func scrollViewWillEndDragging(UIScrollView, withVelocity: CGPoint,
>   targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer) Tells the delegate
>   when the user finishes scrolling the content.
>
> func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(UIScrollView) Tells the delegate when
>   the scroll view is about to start scrolling the content.

It only specifies that the user was the one that triggered the scrolling in `scrollViewWillEndDragging` in the docs, not sure about `scrollViewWillBeginDragging`. But I tried it in xcode and it was working for me.

EDIT: You might also have to take a look at `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` and `scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating` in case a user swipes very hard to the bottom and lets go immediately